# Ошибка запроса к Oracle

Tags: python, oracle

Есть запрос из python скрипта в db oracle

```
sql = "select VEH_ID, lt_vehicles.VEH_TYPE_NO, veh_mod_model_no AS VEH_MODEL_NO,\
     terms_bra.CST_TERM AS VEH_BRAND,\
     lt_model_intl_terms.MIT_TERM as VEH_MODEL_INTL,\
     MOD_INTERNATIONAL_DESIGNATION AS VEH_MODEL_LOCAL,\
     terms_mod.CST_TERM as VEH_TYPE_NAME,\
     ENGINE_CODE,\
     VEA_VAT_VEHICLE_ATT_TYPE_ID, VAT_COMMENT,\
     VAT_KTA_TABLE_NO, VEA_VALUE, VEA_VALUE_TO, KVA_TE_TERM_NO, TE_TERM\
     from lt_vehicles\
     left join lt_model_series on lt_vehicles.veh_mod_model_no=lt_model_series.mod_model_no\
     left join lt_model_intl_terms on lt_model_series.mod_id=lt_model_intl_terms.mit_mod_id and MIT_LNG_LANGUAGE_NO=" + str(
    lang) + "\
     left join gd_brands on lt_model_series.mod_bra_brand_no=gd_brands.bra_brand_no\
     left join gd_countryspecific_terms terms_bra on gd_brands.bra_cst_term_no=terms_bra.cst_term_no and terms_bra.cst_lng_language_no=" + str(
    lang) + "\
     left join gd_countryspecific_terms terms_mod on lt_vehicles.veh_cst_term_no=terms_mod.cst_term_no and terms_mod.cst_lng_language_no=" + str(
    lang) + "\
     left join lt_vehicle_attributes on lt_vehicle_attributes.vea_veh_id=lt_vehicles.veh_id\
     left join lt_vehicle_attribute_types on lt_vehicle_attributes.VEA_VAT_VEHICLE_ATT_TYPE_ID=lt_vehicle_attribute_types.VAT_VEHICLE_ATT_TYPE_ID\
     left join gd_key_values on gd_key_values.KVA_KTA_TABLE_NO=lt_vehicle_attribute_types.VAT_KTA_TABLE_NO and gd_key_values.kva_value_key=VEA_VALUE\
     left join gd_terms on gd_terms.te_term_no=gd_key_values.KVA_TE_TERM_NO and gd_terms.TE_LNG_LANGUAGE_NO=" + str(
    lang) + "\
     left join (\
                select VEN_VEH_TYPE_NO as VEH_TYPE_NO, LISTAGG(EN_ENGINE_CODE,',') WITHIN GROUP (order by VEN_VEH_TYPE_NO) as ENGINE_CODE\
                from lt_veh_engine_assignments\
                left join lt_engines on lt_veh_engine_assignments.VEN_EN_ENGINE_NO=lt_engines.en_engine_no\
                group by VEN_VEH_TYPE_NO\
               ) t_engines on lt_vehicles.veh_type_no=t_engines.veh_type_no\
     order by BRA_SHORT_NAME, VEH_ID, MOD_INTERNATIONAL_DESIGNATION, VEA_VAT_VEHICLE_ATT_TYPE_ID"

cur.execute(sql)
```

Стал возвращать ошибку     `cur.execute(sql) cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long`

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема, так как ранее отрабатывал отлично

Comment: *в чем может быть проблема* А перевести сообщение об ошибке сил не хватило, что ли?

Comment: LISTAGG() возвращает VARCHAR2. В Oracle столбец VARCHAR2 может содержать не более 4000 символов. Варианты решения - (1) переход на XMLAGG (2) создание собственной функции агрегирования, возвращающей CLOB, а не VARCHAR2. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boracle%5D+ORA-01489%3A+result+of+string+concatenation+is+too+long

Comment: Да перевел я сообщение об ошибке!